# Should I be using Java or Python for Android Development?

Tags: android, python

Sorry if this is a duplicate:
I have a good few hours put into learning Python and all good. However I would like to make android apps.
Would I be better of changing to learning Java and how much python overlaps with Java or would knowing a small bit of Python help me?

Comment: For Android, Java!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Android development, you have a few different options, but for most use cases you should probably use Java. Most of the APIs and SDKs Have a look at the SDK documentation here: [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/index.html?utm_source=en-ha-na-sem&utm_medium=text&utm_content=bkws&utm_campaign=android&gclid=CjwKEAjwlpbIBRCx4eT8l9W26igSJAAuQ_HGlVYuDermIN_3paL0mrdt-rmzDU9vgYAKa1wjX3x-PxoCWWHw_wcB&dclid=CPn6zozJzNMCFVBSDAod3AUCPg).

You technically can do development with C/C++ as well with the [Native Development Kit](https://developer.android.com/ndk/index.html) but this should only be used for low level use cases you can't achieve with the Java APIs.

[Scala for Android](http://scala-android.org/) is also an option, as Scala and Java both run on the JVM, compile to the same byte code, and you can call Java APIs from Scala and vice versa.

There are also frameworks which allow you to write your mobile apps in a single language and have a single code base compile to mobile apps on iOS, Android and Windows.  See [Xamarin](https://www.xamarin.com/) for writing apps in C#, or [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) for writing apps in JavaScript/HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 1):

In general you should be using Java, but if you want to try writing Android apps in Python you can check out Kivy: https://kivy.org/

But certainly "knowing a small bit of Python" will help you to learn Java or any other language, as you have already learned a number of general programming concepts.